# Webview android displays blank page

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, pdf-viewer

I need to display and open pdf file in android webview. I have tried many codes here but everytime I open fragment webview displays blank screen.

Below is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.ViewerFragment">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is my kotlin code:

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            }

            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            }
        }


        webView.settings?.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings?.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        webView.settings?.builtInZoomControls = true
        webView.settings?.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings?.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        webView.settings?.useWideViewPort = true
        webView.settings?.displayZoomControls = false
        webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=${url}")
```

Many times pdf displays within seconds. But many times onPageFinished gets called and webview displays blank page.

Anyone have any idea about this problem?

Comment: Use `https` and ensure that you have the `INTERNET` permission.

Comment: Internet permission is already provided. Whole app is on internet only and other things are working fine. Just pdf many times display blank page in webview.

Also, pdf which I am trying to open is already https

Comment: Yes, but `http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=${url}` is not using `https`.

Comment: Yes, I tried ```https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=${url}```as well. Still no luck. Gives the same output.